# Adding or deleting from a table according to another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table something like this one:

```
table1:
Id    License    Major     time 
 2    9          0012      1:2
 1    8          0014      1:2 
 2    9          0017      2:5
 1    7          0016      2:7
 1    6          0019      2:8
```

and I have the other table something like this one:

```
table2
Id   License     Major   
 1     8           0014
 1     7           0016
 1     10          0019
```

I want to delete from or add records to table1 according to table2.
so after deleting and adding from table1 according to table2 this will be table1

```
table1
Id  License    Major     time
2    9           0012     1:2
1    8           0014     1:2
2    9           0017     2:5
1    7           0016     2:7
1    10          0019     Now
```

what is the needed query for implementing it

Comment: Why do you keep license 9, but drop license 6?

Comment: suppose I have two users that their Id's are 1 and 2.and user 1 is editing his/her Majors and licenses. and wants to remove License6.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED answer**

Adding to table1 from table2

```
INSERT INTO table1
  (Id,
  License,
  Major,
  time)
SELECT 
  Id,
  License,
  Major,
  GetDate()
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 on t1.ID = t2.ID and t1.License = t2.License
WHERE t1.ID IS NULL
```

Deleting from table1

```
DELETE
FROM table2 t2
WHERE NOT Exists (SELECT
                License
              FROM table1 t1
              Where t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.License = t2.License)
```

Updating table1 (Assuming you would want to update the changed records as well)

```
Update t1
  SET License = t2.License,
      Major = t2.Major,
      time = GetDate()   
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 on t2.ID = t1.ID and t2.License = t1.License
WHERE t1.Major <> t2.Major
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming table2 has the TIME column

```
begin tran
;
delete table1 where id in (select id from table2)
;
insert table1 (Id, License, Major, time)
select Id, License, Major, time
from table2
;
commit
```

If table2 does not have a TIME column, then it's hard to work with your data. What is "1:2"? Is that some heretofore unknown time format? And what should "Now" produce, in the same format?

If "1:2" just represents a regular datetime, and times are kept from table1 *on the proviso* that (1) License & Major in table2 match an existing License & Major in table1, then

```
begin tran
;
delete a
from table1 a
left join table2 b
    on a.id=b.id and a.license=b.license and a.major=b.major
where b.id is null
;
insert table1 (Id, License, Major, time)
select a.Id, a.License, a.Major, GetDate()
from table2 a
left join table1 b
    on a.id=b.id and a.license=b.license and a.major=b.major
where b.id is null
;
commit
```